# How to scale buffer images of the lwjgl Display

Tags: lwjgl

I wanted to know how I could change the scale of the buffer images so that I could render a resolution of say 320x240 as 640x480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what to do:

For 2D games you can set the screen resolution with the 'setDisplayMode' method, but if you want the screen to be scaled to whatever you want, you have to change the width and height of the 'glOrtho' method to the scaled resolution you want.

Here is an example:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
...
glOrtho(0, width/scale, height/scale, 0, 1, -1);
```